# Calculating Fibonnaci sequence lazily

Tags: c#, fibonacci-sequence, generator, lazy

**Implementation:**

```
IEnumerable<BigInteger> Fibs()
{
    BigInteger a = 0;
    BigInteger b = 1;
    while(true)
    {
        b = a + (a = b);
        yield return a;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
void Main()
{
    // take first 100 fib numbers
    var fibs = Fibs().Take(100);
}
```

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 11):

That's a pretty *clever* implementation. To improve this, I would take some of the cleverness out of it. In particular:

```
while (true)
{
    BigInteger next = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = next;
    yield return next;
}
```

2 lines longer, but no unnecessary cleverness. Perfectly clear, nice and simple, and should be just as efficient. It's good general rule to not try to be too clever. Keep it simple.

Also, `FibonacciSequence` would be a better name than `Fibs`.

Finally, as a tiny remark, put a space before opening parenthese of the `while` condition (like I did above, different from the original code).

Comment: Why not `yield return` as soon as you calculate `next`?

Answer (score 4):

The Fibonacci sequence is just one of many [generalized Fibonacci sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers).  You can get extra flexibility for the same amount of work by taking default parameters.

```
IEnumerable<BigInteger> Fibs(BigInteger a=0, BigInteger b=1)
{
    while(true)
    {
        b = a + (a = b);
        yield return a;
    }
}
```

Bonus: you've saved two lines of code — whether or not you take @janos's advice to reduce the cleverness.  ☺

However, it would be awkward to yield the sum of the parameters `a` and `b` as the first result.  I'd expect it to yield `a`, then `b`, as the first two results.

```
IEnumerable<BigInteger> Fibs(BigInteger a=1, BigInteger b=1)
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return a;
        b = a + (a = b);
    }
}
```

With that, you can use `Fibs(0, 1)` to obtain a Fibonacci sequence starting with 0:

> 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, …

Also, while Fibonacci numbers famously appear in plant growth patterns, it's less well known that sometimes [other sequences](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14-NdQwKz9w) appear, such as `Fibs(1, 3)`:

> 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, …

Comment: for(BigInteger a = 0,b = 1;;b = a + (a = b)) yield return b;

Comment: No, that for loop implements the opposite of my suggestions.  I don't like it.

Comment: I didn't know about other fibonnaci sequences.

Comment: I like your review.

Comment: You can't set parameter defaults like that: "A value of type 'int' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger'." I would probably use `Nullable`: `IEnumerable<BigInteger> Fibs(BigInteger? a = null, BigInteger? b = null)`.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the other answers here, but one more thing to add:

Are you sure you want to use `while(true)`? The answer may very well be yes, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2740023/306918) StackOverflow answer highlights some things to consider when using an "infinite" enumerator.

For example, `Min`, `Max`, `Average`, etc. methods will not fail gracefully. In the linked answer, Marc suggests adding a `SanityCheck` extension method that just puts an upper limit on how many iterations it'll process before throwing its hands in the air and calling it an invalid operation (or simply taking a max iterations argument to the method).

Answer (score 0):

In case you need random access to Fibonacci numbers, one approach is to calculate them once and store them in an array for fast access later on.

```
public static BigInteger[] GetFibonacciArray(int n) 
{
    BigInteger[] a = new BigInteger[n];
    a[0] = new BigInteger(0);
    a[1] = new BigInteger(1);
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = BigInteger.Add(a[i-1], a[i-2]);
    return a;
}
```